# [GitHub Actions]: Remove files and push changes

Tags: git, github-actions, github-pages

Hey I am trying to remove the content of a directory (the directory is called `scss`) via a GitHub Workflow and push to a seperate branch. I am using `actions-js/push@master` for the pushing. However, before that I am compressing some other files. So the workflow looks something like this:

1. Compress HTML, CSS and JS files.
2. Delete the folder `scss` and his content.
3. Push the everything to another branch.

Step 1 & 3 are working perfectly fine however, the `scss` folder is still there.
My `yaml` files looks like this:

```
name: Compress Website
...
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}

    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        os: [ubuntu-20.04]
    env:
      prepo: ${{github.repository}}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set up Minify Actions
        uses: amireshoon/minifyAction@main
        with:
          repo: $prepo
      - name: Minifying Codes
        run: |
          minifier.sh $prepo
================== THIS FAILS ================== 
      - name: Removing unnecessary files
        run: |
          ls -la
          rm -rf scss
          ls -la
================================================ 
      - name: Pushing to production branch
        uses: actions-js/push@master
        with:
          github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          directory: github/workspace
          branch: compressed-master
          message: Minified css, js and html
          author_name: MinifyAction[bot]
          author_email: amireshoon-minifyAction@users.noreply.github.com
          force: true
```

The output of the `ls` statements shows me that the folder has been deleted but when I look at the pushed files it is still there. Why does step 2 not work?

Comment: `rm` removes files from a *working tree*. It has no effect on a *Git repository*. Note also that `git push` does not push *files*, it pushes *commits;* you must make a new commit. Git builds a new commit from Git's *index* aka *staging area*, not from the working tree. Consider using `git rm`, which removes files from both the working tree *and* the staging area. However, you should reconsider the idea of storing build products in Git at all: that's generally a bad plan.

Comment: @torek I know you don't like storing generated files in Git, but it's how GitHub pages works! This workflow feels to me like a publication workflow, which the tag github-pages confirms. Please don't advise against using the documented way to publish websites through GitHub pages.

Comment: @Josip, torek's advice is otherwise correct: operations in the CI workflow must go through the Git index, so `git rm` rather than `rm`, and `git add`, `git commit` etc, not operations directly in the working tree.

Comment: @joanis: For "text" (GitHub Pages) files the effect tends not to be that bad, but I do wish GitHub would provide some sort of artifact storage system. Then again first we need to write an appropriate artifact storage system. :-) (Basically, with a *smart* storage system, we'd keep generated artifacts as a sort of cache, and rebuild them on demand. But this needs a lot of fancy footwork since we sometimes lose the ability to rebuild.)

Comment: Frankly, I find GitHub pages a strange beast: the artifact storage system is a separate branch in your git repo on GitHub, where typically none of you actual source files go, only  whatever form they need to be transformed into on the published web site. In some ways, though, they have a point: why require another storage system when we already have branches in the Git repo? In the end, it works, it gets your web site up and running for free (as long as it's all static and open source) and an incredible number of small web sites are published that way all over the web.

Comment: I imagine if and when the web site gets big with lots of images and larger files, though, that'll start taxing the model and probably stop working so well, or least it'll get clunkier and slower to clone and all that.

Comment: @torek and joanis Thank you guys, you pointed me in the right direction however, modifying the working tree was not the problem. The problem was essentialy that I made the changes in the wrong directory and this took me way longer to realise than it should have 

Comment: @torek And I am storing this build product because it is being served as a Github page. Otherwhise I agree with you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments of @torek and @joanis pointed me to the right direction but the issue lies not with modifying the working tree.

Although it is true that I am only modifying the working tree the action `actions-js/push@master` takes care of committing the changes. So modifying the working tree should indeed be enough to see the changes reflected in my new branch. However, I passed the argument `directory: github/workspace` for the action which switches the directory before pushing.

First I did not know where this directory comes from (I copied a working.yaml file) but when looking at the [source code](https://github.com/amireshoon/minifyAction/blob/main/script/minifier.sh) of the minifying action (`amireshoon/minifyAction@main`) the picture becomes clearer:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Creating workspace
mkdir github && cd github
git clone https://github.com/$1.git workspace
cd workspace
...
```

The minifying action creates said directory by cloning the project again and proceeds to minify the files in that directory. **So naturally, all the changes I made in my working tree are not reflected because the push is performed for a different local repository that is contained in `github/workspace`.**

So to fix the issue you can **perform your changes in that directory**. Although I ended up using another minifying action that modifies the working tree directly. So all changes are made in the same directory and finally pushed with `actions-js/push@master` without specifying a special directory.

My working action looks like this:

```
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}

    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        os: [ubuntu-20.04]
    env:
      prepo: ${{github.repository}}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Removing unnecessary files
        run: |
          rm -r scss
          ls -la
      - name: minify css
        uses: nizarmah/auto-minify@v2.1
        with:
          overwrite: true
          directory: 'css'
      - name: minify js
        uses: nizarmah/auto-minify@v2.1
        with:
          overwrite: true
          directory: 'js/custom'
      - name: Pushing to production branch
        uses: actions-js/push@master
        with:
          github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          branch: compressed-master
          message: Minified css, js and html
          author_name: MinifyAction[bot]
          author_email: amireshoon-minifyAction@users.noreply.github.com
          force: true
```

This was a really long answer for a really silly mistake but it hopes it helps someone out in the future.